# memory error (memory leaks) in python multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, memory-management, memory-leaks, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run some heavy data processing. For that, I use Python multiprocessing but without any success. All the time I run the code it either is MemoeryError or the processes are hung and do not do anything( or at least I think they are just hanging). I searched across the SO, there are many similar questions and I've tested almost all of them but did not work.

Any help would be appreciated. I already spend days to find a bug but no success

Here is my code

```
import tqdm
import multiprocessing

# This reads all the data as a generator
batches = get_batches(dat_iter=gzip_to_records(input_cache_path), batch_size=batch_size)

# initialize output file
out_cache = gzip.open(output_cache_path, mode='wt')

# iterate on batches
for batch in tqdm.tqdm(batches, leave=False, desc=f"Running on batches of size: {batch_size}"):

    # run multiprocessing pool for each batch
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=args.processes) as pool:

        # generate equally distributed chunks of data for each process from batch
        chunks = get_chunks(data=batch, processes=processes)

        # create map arguments from chunks and function arguments
        map_args = [(chk,) for chk in chunks]

        # reduce all maps from processes to collect full extracted batch
        batch_extractions = pool.starmap(extract_data, map_args)

        # append batch data to output cache
        append_to_cache(batch_extractions, writer=out_cache)


    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```